# How Do I Calculate Audio Gain using C#?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, lowpass-filter

I have the following low pass filter c# code which reduces the power of my audio making it's volume very low. I want to increase it's power/amplify it by multiplying with gain. I want to know by how much gain should I multiply to maintain the intensity of audio after filtering.

Here is my code:

```
    public MyFilter(ISampleProvider sourceProvider,int cutOffFreq)
    {
        this.sourceProvider = sourceProvider;
        this.cutOffFreq = cutOffFreq;

        channels = sourceProvider.WaveFormat.Channels;
        filters = new BiQuadFilter[channels];
        CreateFilters();
    }

    private void CreateFilters()
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < channels; n++)
            if (filters[n] == null)
                filters[n] = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
            else
                filters[n].SetLowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return sourceProvider.WaveFormat; } }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int samplesRead = sourceProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < samplesRead; i++)
            buffer[offset + i] = filters[(i % channels)].Transform(buffer[offset + i]);

        return samplesRead;
    }
```

Comment: If the output of the filter is low then your original signal had a lot of energy in the stop band and not much energy in the pass band.  Adding gain is just going to bring back up the level of the signal you filtered out except with a lot of added noise. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish an increase in volume....A very rough example is suppose I have my audio playing at volume level 1 then after filtering it seems as if the volume level has dropped down to 0.5 thus making it barely audible....but i want to keep level to 1 only even after filtering...
Overall, I want to keep power/intensity of volume same but just filter it.

Comment: What is your cutoff freq?

Comment: 1500Hz, 1000Hz, 850 Hz, 750Hz and 650 Hz...I will be playing my audios in a loop with these cut off freq...1st being 1500 and last being 650

Comment: Can you attach a sample of the waveform before filtering? Also indicate the sample rate.

Answer (score 0):

How much the volume decreases after filtering depends from the audio signal and the cut-off frequency. The energy in the signal must be calculated before and after filtering. Then the loss is known and the gain can be adjusted accordingly.

There are at least two methods to calculate the energy of an audio signal. The first (and I think the easier method) is to calculate the so called Root Mean Square Energy (RMSE):

Formula as pseudo code:

```
foreach( sample in audioSignal)
{
  sum += sqr( sample )
}
sum /= samples.Count
RMSE = sqrt( sum );
```

The RMSE corresponds quite well with the energy of the signal. It must be calculated for the orignal signal and the filtered signal. Then the difference is known and the gain may be adjusted.

Instead to calculate the energy for points in time with RMSE it also possible to calulate the energy for every frequency of the signal. To do this, the spectrum of the signal is calculated with a Fast Fourier Transformation (FFT).
After the FFT the amplitudes for the frequencies in the signal are known. They correspond with the energy carried by each frequency. Calculate the sum of the amplitudes to get the complete energy of the audio signal. Do this for the signal with and without filtering. Subtract the results and adjust the gain by the given value.